# Is badblocks in read-write mode as effective with a solid state hybrid drive as with a hard disk drive?

Tags: hybrid-storage, bad-blocks

## Question

Is `badblocks` in read-write mode as effective with a solid state hybrid drive (SSHD) as with a hard disk drive (HDD)?

More specifically:

- if all blocks of the device are written in that mode, will it allow the controller to identify any bad blocks?

### Background

[Ubuntu Manpage: badblocks - search a device for bad blocks](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/intrepid/man8/badblocks.8.html)

I assume that a non-destructive **read-only** test of blocks of an SSHD:

- would read some blocks from the SSD level alone
- and so, might produce a misleading overview of the state of things at the HDD level.

I expect a **read-write** test to be more effective. This assumes that all writes will eventually flush to HDD.

### Example

With option `-n` for non-destructive read-write mode:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/dev$ sudo badblocks -n -s -v /dev/sda
Checking for bad blocks in non-destructive read-write mode
From block 0 to 732574583
Checking for bad blocks (non-destructive read-write test)
Testing with random pattern:   0.23% done, 1:47 elapsed
                               0.92% done, 7:09 elapsed
                               1.00% done, 7:46 elapsed
                              25.13% done, 3:49:32 elapsed
                              25.13% done, 3:49:33 elapsed
                              25.13% done, 3:49:34 elapsed
                              25.13% done, 3:49:35 elapsed
```

#### Related

In Ask Different:

- the **first edition of [an answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/75788/8546)** to [What free or open source software can I use with Mac hardware to verify integrity of every block of a disk where Core Storage is used?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/57869/8546)

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for the thread necromancy, but I stumbled across this question while searching for a similar answer.

According to a [review from AnandTech](http://www.anandtech.com/show/3734/seagates-momentus-xt-review-finally-a-good-hybrid-hdd/1), SSHD drives like Seagate's Momentus and FireCuda do not use the SSD cache for write operations; just reads.  The SSD read cache should only populate for sectors that have been requested from the platters multiple times, and thus should not be in use during a `badblocks` pass. Therefore, a destructive read/write `badblocks` test should operate in exactly the same fashion as one would expect from a plain mechanical drive.

My only concern would be the unlikely scenario in which a sector does fail, but is cached in the NAND layer.  Read requests for that sector would not hit the spindle, and would be fetched from the SSD cache.  Again, though, I do not believe this to be feasible during a `badblocks` run.

I would still pair it with a S.M.A.R.T. extended or conveyance test and check for reallocated sectors, just to be on the safe side.  If you were not already aware, please note that on Seagate drives, the [seek error rate, raw read error rate, and hardware ECC recovered](http://www.users.on.net/~fzabkar/HDD/Seagate_SER_RRER_HEC.html) attributes only indicate problems if the uppermost 16 bits are used; fluctuations in the lower 32 bits are normal, and indicate usage values for the drive (e.g., number of seeks and reads performed).